# Are the MUX with 3 inputs and AND with 2 inputs gate the same?

Tags: logic-gates

I have a MUX with 3 inputs, `a`, `b`, and `reset`. The `b` input is always low. Is this the same as an AND gate with 2 inputs, `reset` and `b`?

I used the truth table to figure out this question, and I thought the answer is no, but my friend said "yes". So i am confused now, can anyone tell me the truth?

Comment: Show the truth table you made. Also note that a MUX requires a control input.

Answer (score 1):

[image: http://fourier.eng.hmc.edu/e85_old/lectures/figures/MUX0.png]

if S = 0, then y = x0
if S = 1, then y = x1

connect x0 to ground

Let's remake the truth table above

if S = 0, then y = 0
if S = 1, then y = x1

So in order for y to be 1, both S has to be 1 **and** x1 has to be 1.

So **yes**, you can make an and gate out of a mux.

Here's some boolean algebra if you still don't trust me.

This is a mux:
\$y = s(x_1)+s'(x_0)\$
\$y = sx_1+s'x_0\$

set \$x_0 = 0\$

\$y = sx_1+s'0\$
\$y = sx_1\$
**\$y = s\$ and \$x_1\$**

Answer (score 0):

This is how the [SN74LVC1G97](http://www.ti.com/product/SN74LVC1G97) is implemented:

[image: SN74LVC1G97 function block diagram]

As shown in its datasheet, when using all three inputs, it is a MUX, and when the correct input is constant low, the remaining two inputs form an AND gate:

[image: SN74LVC1G97 circuits]

This can also be seen in the truth table, when looking only at the entries that remain when `In1 = 0`:

[image: SN74LVC1G97 truth table for AND]